# Can we use component one studio enterprise to create stand alone HTML5 web application?

Tags: html, componentone, wijmo

Can we use component one studio enterprise to create stand alone HTML5 web application ?

It seems like "wijmo javascripts/html5 widgets" belongs to "Studio for ASP.Net" of "Studio enterprise package". After installed it, we cannot find the related things to "wijmo javascripts/html5 widgets" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\ComponentOne\Studio for ASP.NET Wijmo" folder. (it shows ASP.NET MVC tools, bin, c1pdf and etc..) How can we use the things of "wijmo javascripts/html5 widgets" in our HTML5 applications from the insatlled machine (if the machine already had license activated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Wijmo widgets to create HTML5 web application and can refer to the following link for more details:
http://wijmo.com/
http://wijmo.com/5/

Comment: Thanks Ashish. what my question is, we have a license for "Component One Studio Enterprise". It shows a list during install that

Comment: Thanks Ashish. what my question is, we have a license for "Component One Studio Enterprise". It shows a below list during install 1.Studio for winforms v2 2.Studio for WPF 3.Studio for Silver light 4.Studio for ASP.Net wijmo 5. Studio for WinRT XAML (8.1) 6.Studio for windows phone 7.Studio for compact framework. 8.Studio for Activex 9.OLAP for winforms 10.Studio for LightSwitch 11.Intellispell 12. xap optimizer. Anyone among the above list can use to create HTML5 application ?. The Studio for ASP.Net wijmo can be used for .Net. As like anything can use for HTML5 ?

Comment: Studio for ASP.NET Wijmo includes Wijmo widgets which you can use for HTML5 application. Here is the link: http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioASPNET/

Comment: Thanks Ashish."Studio for ASP.NET" comes under "ComponentOne studio enterprise" package. We have installed and activated license. We are able to access c1 controls for ASP.NET. But we are not able to find any HTML5 widgets in "C:\Program Files\ComponentOne\Studio for ASP.NET Wijmo\". So Where we can get the widget grid control for HTML5 ? I want to include the HTML5 widget control from the Tool box. So how to include the widgets in toolbox ?

Comment: Replied at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750812/cannot-find-wijmo-grid-wijgrid-control-on-component-one-studio-enterprises-stu/