# Cannot find wijmo.grid.wijgrid control on Component One Studio Enterprise's "Studio for ASP.NET wijmo" installation

Tags: html, componentone, wijmo

I have installed the Studio for ASP.NET wijmo with license activated. I can use the c1 controls for ASP.NET applications. Now I wish to use the "wijgrid" and other widgets for HTML5 application. I looked into this folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\ComponentOne\Studio for ASP.NET Wijmo" to any subfolder available for HTML5 widgets. But I can see only the folders 1. ASP.NET MVC Tools 2. bin 3. c1excel etc.. and not any folders for HTML5 widgets. And if I try to include tools in HTML tab in toolbox, all the controls found in the name started with c1. I searched in the internet, it seems for wijmo grid widget we have to use "wijmo.grid.wijgrid" namespace. In which folder we get the HTML5 widgets and how to include in HTML5 application ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wijmo widgets come under the Studio for ASP.NET package but these are jQuery based widgets. hence, you won't see them in toolbox. You can download the from the following link ;
http://wijmo.com/downloads/

and start creating widgets with the help of following link:
http://wijmo.com/docs/wijmo/webframe.html#Grid.html

Comment: Thanks. We got a workable solution with dynamic data with wijgrid. Now, how should we mapped the wijmo widgets downloads with our existing Studio enterprise license in order to implement in production ?